# multiple divs with useRef

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

Assuming that I have multiple divs and the action onClick is the same for each one.
how can i get what Ref has been clicked?

I've tried and I am struggling.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const Ref1 = useRef();
  const Ref2 = useRef();
  const Ref3 = useRef();

  const Namee = event => {
    let temp = event.currentTarget.id;

    temp == "Ref1" ? (Ref1.current.style.display = "none") : null;
    temp == "Ref2" ? (Ref2.current.style.display = "none") : null;
    temp == "Ref3" ? (Ref3.current.style.display = "none") : null;
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div id="Ref1" ref={Ref1} onClick={Namee} className="icon-wrapper">
        jjjjj
      </div>
      <div id="Ref2" ref={Ref2} onClick={Namee} className="icon-wrapper">
        jeee
      </div>
      <div id="Ref3" ref={Ref3} onClick={Namee} className="icon-wrapper">
        jeee
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aucoxt << is this example, which obv is inefficient as I need to repeat the display: none

Comment: sorry I can't upvote you. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

You could just pass the ref into the onClick function:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const Ref1 = useRef();
  const Ref2 = useRef();
  const Ref3 = useRef();

  const Namee = (ref) => ref.current.style.display = "none";

  return (
    <>
      <div id="Ref1" ref={Ref1} onClick={() => Namee(Ref1)} className="icon-wrapper">
        jjjjj
      </div>
      <div id="Ref2" ref={Ref2} onClick={() => Namee(Ref2)} className="icon-wrapper">
        jeee
      </div>
      <div id="Ref3" ref={Ref3} onClick={() => Namee(Ref3)} className="icon-wrapper">
        jeeea
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Edit: depending on what you want to achieve you could maybe also keep track of your data with a useState hook and then iterate over that to render the divs instead of having 3 divs with a ref each from the start.
You could have an array of objects with a key value pair 'show' which is true or false. And then you render your divs based on that if you know what I mean. But I am not totally sure what you are doing so maybe that does not make sense for your use case.

Comment: thanks mate. Yeah I was basically looking to do some dropdown boxes that open onclick, and close onclick. So your suggestion relevant. thanks for responding to this as fast as u did.